# Escape reserved words in JPQL

Tags: java, jpql

I want to write JPQL, which returns all my entities. The problem is that entity is  called "Case", and this is a restricted word. Does JPQL has some escape characters? How to write this JPQL?

```
SELECT c from Case
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: JPQL as i know works with object names not with table names. So the escaping should be done by jpa

Comment: Case in this example is an entity name - no table. The problem is that is word [case](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.3.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_case_expressions) is restricted.

Comment: Have you tried to running the query? you get any error?

Comment: Have you tried to make Case as fully qualified java class name, like: `SELECT c from my.example.Case`?

Comment: @Piotr Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  :( I change a name of entity