# How to escape reserved keywords which are Entity names in JPQL - Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a simple JOIN query that I need to run between Table_A and Order but because Order is a reserved Keyword I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Order near line 1
```

Here is the Query:

```
List<Tuple> list  = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select a " +
                        "from Table_A a " +
                        "join Order o on a.orderID = o.orderID " +
                        "where o.status = :status ", Tuple.class)
                .setParameter("status", "Completed")
                .getResultList();
```

I have gone through questions where people have similar difficulties but the questions asked have been issues with the column names and those fortunately have a workaround but when the keyword is the entity name I haven't been able to find a solution. I dont want to change the class name because of this hurdle and I was wondering if someone has encountered a similar issue and can help me with my problem.

Someone who posted a similar question hasnt been answered yet, check out this link:
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33144550/escape-reserved-words-in-jpql)

People having trouble with column names have solved it by doing the following:

[Question_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619630/jpa-hibernate-escaping-hql-keywords)

[Question_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686412/how-to-escape-reserved-words-in-hibernates-hql)

Comment: Can you use native query ?

Comment: How did you even create table Order?

Comment: Use a JPA provider that does it for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use Order as an entity name because it's a reserved keyword in JPQL.

If you don't want to change the name of the class you can change the entity name like this, where "TheOrder" would be the name you want to use.

And you will also need to change the table name because Order is also a reserved keyword in SQL.

```
@Table(name = "TheOrder")
@Entity(name = "TheOrder")
public class Order
```

But now you have to use TheOrder instead of Order in your JPQL queries:

```
List<Tuple> list  = entityManager.createQuery(
            "select a " +
                    "from Table_A a " +
                    "join TheOrder o on a.orderID = o.orderID " +
                    "where o.status = :status ", Tuple.class)
            .setParameter("status", "Completed")
            .getResultList();
```

In my opinion this will lead to more confusion. So better change the name of the class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, this helped me a lot. Although there is one small weird behavior that I noticed, after adding @Entity(name = "TheOrder") I was getting org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TheOrder is not mapped error but then i ran one successful test by giving full path of the class and it worked and then i revered back to query you posted and now it still works

Answer (score 2):

A better alternative without changing the name of the table is to escape the name within the query using most popular escaping characters, e.g. using backticks (``), quotes or double quotes around the table or column name depending on your case.

I had a similar problem when one of my tables was named Group, and even initially when making the SQL migration files I had to escape the name.
For example:

```
CREATE TABLE "group"
```

When I performed a simple built-in `findAll` from the repository I got the following exception `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"`

So, I realized the problem was the reserved keyword `group`.
To avoid editing, renaming, refactoring, etc. I decided to try escaping the name somehow within the entity class.

Luckily, this can be achieved by specifying the table name in the `@Table` annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"group\"")
public class Group...
```

After this, it knew how to escape this reserved keyword when executing queries under the hood.

I tested if backticks would work in place of `\"`, and it also does the trick.

```
@Table(name = "`group`")
```

You can also use this method in combination with `@Column` to avoid such issues with columns that are named with reserved keywords, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74739157/20649145).